# MySQL 5.7 - JSON - Searching array of KV objects

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, json

Version: MySQL 5.7.25, GCP CloudSQL.

I'm looking to store Twilio SMS delivery status updates in MySQL. I wanted to try using JSON for this to store one record per SMS, but then have a JSON column to update an array of KV objects with the statuses. First time we're really looking at using MySQL's JSON functionality.

The CREATE table, roughly, looks like (ignore the lack of indexes):

```sql
create table sms_notification (
    id bigint(20) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    msg_id varchar(190),
    company_id bigint(20),
    from_user_id bigint(20),
    to_number varchar(150),
    `body` text,
    created datetime default now() not null,
    status JSON not null
    ) charset=utf8mb4;
```

An insert into this table could roughly look like:

```
INSERT INTO sms_notification (id, msg_id, company_id, from_user_id, to_number, body, created, status)
VALUES (
  2, 'msg_ac829d...' 384, 2677, '+1xxx', 'Second message', '2020-01-28 22:12:41',
'[{"time": "2019-01-01 00:00:00", "status": "sent"}, {"time": "2019-01-02 00:00:00", "status": "failed"}]'
);
```

Key here is storing all status updates we get from a twilio webhook about a specific message in one record.

Playing around with queries I am running into limitations of how to search for certain things

Grabbing all failed messages for a user can be done with a %-like query:
`select * from sms_notification where to_number = '+1xxx' and status like '%failed%';`

But querying json like that seems... to not really make it any different than a text field.

I've attempted to use the json_contains and json_search but MySQL seems to struggle with array searches - or more likely I have my query set up incorrectly.

Searching array paths on the status field can be `$[*].status`, or `$**.status` if I understand correctly, but neither appear to be able to be used in a WHERE?

Neither
`select * from sms_notification where json_extract(status, '$[*].status') = 'delivered';`
nor `select * from sms_notification where json_contains(status, 'delivered', '$**.status')` appear to work. Neither do combinations of different path searches in either json function.

Am I completely misunderstanding how to use json in searches, or is this a limitation of searching an array of objects in MySQL?

Comment: Any chance I can convince you to switch to Postgres? It has *extensive* JSON support.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to spin up a pgsql 11 and see what that can do for me

Comment: Great! Any reason why you're not trying the latest version which is now 12? It even has "SQL/JSON path expression support".

Comment: GCP CloudSQL doesn't have 12 in their managed context yet. We don't have capacity to manage our own HA pgsql configs, etc.

Comment: even mysql 6.7 has enough josn https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html to get around and finding everything even in where clauses. It takes some time to get used to it, but switching to postgre will need also some time. If you struggle with one query simpy post an set of example data and the result you want and you will get here or on so an answer.

Comment: Use JSON only for data that is unlikely to ever be searched on.  In general, use RDBMS features of tables, columns, rows; it is more powerful.